# Increase reponse size limit in sharepoint cross-domain library

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp179895.aspx), the response-size expected shouldn't be more than 200 kb when using the cross-domain library with web proxy. Is it possible to increase this limit?

I am trying to build a sharepoint-hosted application.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2014/01/24/SPWebProxy-response-limit-_2D00_-Increasing-It_2100_.aspx) I've found a solution that works for me. I am on-premise:

```
$contentService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$type = $contentService.gettype()
$config = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebProxyConfig
$configType = $config.gettype()
$methods = $Type.GetMethods() | where-object {$_.Name -eq "GetChild"}
$gm = $methods[1].MakeGenericMethod($configType)
$realConfig = $gm.Invoke( $contentService , $null)
if ($realConfig -eq $Null)
{
$config.update()
$realConfig = $gm.Invoke( $contentService , $null)
}
$realConfig.MaxResponseSize = 400000  #this is an Integer so up to 2GB
$realConfig.update()
```